# How to check if a number is between a range

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem for an online course I am doing. The question is:

Given an Integer x, write a program which generates random numbers between x and 0 until each number in this range has been generated at least once. Once all numbers in this range have been generated, the program should display the numbers which were generated.

I have written a program which I thought would solve this but am having problems with the checking if a number is in the range. Here is my code so far:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random generator = new Random();
        ArrayList<Integer> range = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int x = 10;
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<x+1; i++){
            range.add(i);
        }

        while(range.isEmpty() != true){
            int temp = generator.nextInt(x-1);
            count++;
            generated.add(temp);
            if(range.contains(temp)){
                range.remove(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My idea was to first create two arraylists. The first would hold all numbers between 0 and the given x. The second would contain the random numbers generated. I then fill the range arraylist with the range between 0 and x. My While loop then checks this range list to see if it is empty. If not, it generates a random number, adds it to my second arraylist. I then check if this number is in the range arraylist - if it is it removes it and carries on. The problem I am having is it is running into IndexOutOfBoundsException after a few goes. I think this is because I am removing the generated numbers from the arraylist. Can anyone help me with fixing this

EDIT: I cant use any collections or other APIs. This part of the course is mainly about using Arrays and loops etc, not advanced Java stuff.

Comment: `set` and `set1` are not declared

Comment: @njzk2 sorry names are still set and set1 in code but should be range and generated, i will change it now

Comment: In **real** code use something like `List<Integer> range = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, x).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()); Collections.shuffle(range, generator); System.out.println(range);`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The assignment isn't to shuffle numbers, but to keep generating random numbers until all the numbers in the range have been generated. E.g. for number in range 0-3, you might get `2,0,2,3,3,2,0,1` as the result.

Comment: @Andreas I understand that, but how do I check when all the numbers have been generated without using Arrays or other data structures?

Comment: @AndyOrchard Make up your mind please. In question you added *"I cant use any collections or other APIs. This part of the course is **mainly about using Arrays** and loops etc, not advanced Java stuff"*, but now you say *"without using Arrays or other data structures"*, so which is it? Is the point to use arrays or not?

Comment: @Andreas what I mean is you have explained the question but havent mentioned using data structures or arrays. I was wondering how you do it without using that as you have merely just rephrased the question without mentioning solutions or tips.

Comment: @AndyOrchard First, my initial comment was addressed to Elliott Frisch, not to you, so I wasn't trying to explain how the assignment should be done, only that Elliott's suggestion wasn't it. But I'll help: Create an **array of booleans** so you can track if the number has been generated yet. Keep generating numbers until all slots in the array are `true`. I mean, the assignment is about testing whether you know how to use arrays, right? So use an array.

Comment: `ArrayList` is a data structure (and a `Collection`), so now your question is even less clear.

Comment: And hint: when you have to create n random numbers out of 0 to n, then there are no random numbers. The only thing that is random here is the order. You could also just create an array with all numbers, and then shuffle the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replace **range.remove(temp);** with **range.removeIf(t -> t == temp);**

```
Random generator = new Random();
        ArrayList<Integer> range = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int x = 10;
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<x+1; i++){
            range.add(i);
        }

        while(range.isEmpty() != true){
            int temp = generator.nextInt(x-1);
            count++;
            generated.add(temp);
            if(range.contains(temp)){
                range.removeIf(t -> t == temp);
            }
        }
```

OR You can use Iterator to remove from the List

```
for (Iterator<Integer> it = range.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                Integer obj= it.next();
                if (obj == temp) {
                    // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
                    it.remove();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

One more issue in your logic
int temp = generator.nextInt(x-1); The random number you are generating doesn't contain all the numbers. It should be int temp = generator.nextInt(x+2);

Comment: What does "range.removeIf(t -> t == temp);"  this line do?

Comment: Please check https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/arraylist/arraylist_removeif.php. Also, there is an issue in random number generation. I have updated my answer. You can also use the Iterator if you want.

Answer (score 1):

`remove` is an overloaded method, there is `remove(int)` which removes the item at the index specified and there is `remove(T)` which removes the first object int the list that is equal to the argument you passed in

since you passed an int to the method not an Integer, the first method is chosen

the simpliest modification to your code is replacing `range.remove(temp);` with `range.remove(range.indexOf(temp));` or `range.remove((Integer)temp)`

also you have to call `generator.nextInt(x+1);` or else the program will be stuck in an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below will meet your requirement.

```
        Random random = new Random();
        int x = 3;
        List<Integer> range = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i <x+1; i++) {
            range.add(i);
        }
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (!list.containsAll(range)) {
            list.add(random.nextInt(x + 1));
        }
        System.out.println(list);
```